# How to delete sorted/filtered items when using UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

The following code successfully creates, displays a list of `Cars` in a `UITableView` where you can later delete carts too. It also presents a `UISearchController` where you can successfully perform searches.

My issue is trying to delete cars after a search/filter, for instance, if the user makes a search for a car which is located in the middle of the array, it will display the right car on the top row of the table but if he/she decides to delete it, it will delete the first item in the `cars` array since the filtered item is always positioned at the top in the `filteredCars` array. Here I get no error, but it does not delete the right item from the `cars` array, it always deletes the first item from the `cars` array.

Here is the code:

### Model

```
class Car{
    var make = ""
    var model = ""
}
```

### ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating{

    var cars =  Array<Car>()
    var filteredCars =  Array<Car>()
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createCars()

        filteredCars = cars

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by model"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredCars.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredCars[indexPath.row].model
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredCars[indexPath.row].make
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, index in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete selected car?", message: "This will permanently delete the selected car, do you want to continue?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: { action in
                self.filteredCars.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.cars.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                self.myTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.left)
            }
            ))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return [delete]
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            filteredCars = searchText.isEmpty ? cars : cars.filter({(dataString: Car) -> Bool in
                return dataString.model.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            })
            myTable.reloadData()
        }
    }
    // create cars manually for demonstration only      
    func createCars(){
        let car1 = Car()
        car1.make = "Ford"
        car1.model = "Explorer"

        //... more cars here

        cars.append(contentsOf: [car1, car2, car3, car4])
    }
}
```

I tried the following but I keep getting an `Index out of range` error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete selected car?", message: "This will permanently delete the selected car, do you want to continue?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: { action in

            self.filteredCars.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.myTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.left)

            for i in 0..<self.cars.count {
                if self.cars[i].model == modelToDelete{
                    self.cars.remove(at:i)
                }
            }
        }
        ))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    return [delete]
}
```

What would be the right logic for deleting items after a search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the index in the main array for the given car

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: { action in
     let carToDelete = self.filteredCars.remove(at: indexPath.row)
     self.cars.remove(at: self.cars.index(of: carToDelete)!)
     tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
}
```

This requires that `Car` adopts `Equatable` which is pretty easy to implement. If you change `class` to `struct` you get `Equatable` for free.

```
class Car : Equatable {
    var make = ""
    var model = ""

    static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.make == rhs.make && lhs.model == rhs.model
    }
}
```

And use always the table view instance passed as parameter.

Comment: Ok, I first need to take a look into how to use `Equatable`, it's a new concept for me. Thanks.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot for your help. Do you think is a good practice to make you all models conform to the `Equatable` protocol since the beginning or only add it when you need it?

Comment: It's good practice to prefer `struct` over `class` as much as possible where Equatable is provided implicitly.

Comment: In my case I'm working with an existing `class` and changing it is not an option, thank you for the advice though.

Comment: And by the way it's bad practice to assign default values to properties as an alibi no to write an initializer.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind pointing out what could be the issue? I ways tend to add default values, this way they will never be nil. Thanks

Comment: With default values you are never able to declare constants (`let`) and with an initializer `init(make: String, model:String)` the values can't be `nil` either.

Comment: I see your point and I think you are right, it's just laziness.  Thank you for the advice, I really appreciate it.

Comment: One last question, in my real-life application I have an object that needs to conform to the `Equatable ` protocol with 14 different properties, `var name:String`, `var price:Double`, `var notes:List<Note>()`, `var id = UUID().uuidString` etc. do I need to list all of them in the `static func == ()-> Bool` method? Can you please elavorate a little on what goes there.

Comment: The static func `==` determines if two objects are regarded as equal. This can be just a name if the names are unique or in the answer two objects are equal if `make` and `model` are the same. In your particular case there is an UUID – which is unique – so it's sufficient to regard two objects as equal if they have the same `id`, just `return lhs.id == rhs.id`

Comment: Ahh, I think I got it, you need to determine what properties from an object can be used to find out if two objects are the same by comparing their values at a later time, in my case the unique identifier is enough since no object will have the same id, correct? Sorry, I feel like I just rephrased what you just said but I need to make sure I got the right message. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - Just for the record, if your class inherits from `NSObject` there is no need to make the class conform to the `Equatable` protocol since `NSObject` already conforms to it.

Comment: Yes, but that's another *lazy* bad practice. Swift's light-weight value types (struct) are more efficient than Objective-C's heavy reference types (NSObject class).

Comment: In my case, I was already inheriting from `NSObject` but it's good to know, thanks.